# View live GPS tracking online during race

Tags: gps

Are there any apps that will allow me to share my current location in real time?

I'm doing a half ironman triathlon  and I want to run/bike with my phone
(GPS enabled) and share my progress in real time.  Is there any app that allows this? I'm thinking my friends/family could go to a particular website and see my progress on a map in real time.

I am aware of apps like endomondo, runkeeper, etc. but they only record GPS data.

Answer (score 1):

If I enable location sharing in Latitude, that comes with Google Maps, all my friends with whom I have enabled sharing can see me either from their phone or logging in to Google Maps.